# Text input inside jQuery UI sortable doesn't work on touch devices

Tags: ipad, jquery-ui, input, touch, jquery-ui-sortable

I made a simple page with some divs being sortable by the jQuery UI Sortable, with a little help from [Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) to get it working on an iPad running iOS 7.1.2.

Inside each of these divs, I included a text input tag. On desktop browsers the inputs work fine, but the iPad doesn't recognize the click on the input component. The keyboard isn't launched and I can't type into it. Any lights?

My page is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5crp55r9jw98var/sortableTest.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's what worked for me.

I edited the jquery.js. On `jQuery.Event.prototype`, inside the `preventDefault` function, there is:

```
if ( e.preventDefault ) {
    e.preventDefault();
} else {
    e.returnValue = false;
}
```

Basically, I changed the if condition to `e.preventDefault && e.target.tagName != "INPUT"`. It solved the example, but in the real life I needed to add some more conditions to ensure that other input fields won't get caught by this.

Answer (score 1):

Change in ***jquery.ui.touch-punch.js*** worked for me.
JS: jquery.ui.touch-punch.js
Method to modify:

```
//line: 31    
function simulateMouseEvent(event, simulatedType) {
 //...
}


//changes to add ++
if ($(event.target).is("input") || $(event.target).is("textarea")) {
    return;
} else {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but got the following to work for me without modifying the JS files:

```
let detectTap = false;

$('body').on('touchstart', '#sortableMenu input', () => {
  detectTap = true;
});
$('body').on('touchmove', '#sortableMenu input', () => {
  detectTap = false;
});
$('body').on('touchend', '#sortableMenu input', (e) => {
  if (detectTap) $(e.target).focus();
});
```

Basically just adding a tap listener on the inputs, and when it gets the tap, focus on that input.